# RTL8821AE windows 10 issue

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, asus-laptop

I have just bought an Asus laptop (R510V) and the internet connection is working well

but, somehow, sometimes the wifi just don't work on some applications, it gets very slow, and if I do a skype call, the wifi starts working correctly
(mainly steam, league of legend launcher, github)
and when I mean slow, I mean its like it was disconnected

and on some other applications I have no problems, (ex speedtest 40mb/s down, 30mb/s up, 9ms ping)

also, I have none of this issues when I connect with my phone sharing internet (usb) and/or with ethernet

I tried to update the drivers, many ways, I just found no solutions

I didn't even find RTL8821AE wireless lan driver on realtek website

any clue, what I should do?

Comment: Did you try it with the computer as close to the router as it is to the phone you tether from?

Comment: my router is already 3 meters away, and I have high speed connection, it just doesn't work on some applications, (and works again with skype calling)
weirdest bug I have ever seen

Comment: You may be surprised but I'm not.  Your problem only happens in applications that generate a lot of communication frames, which makes that traffic more susceptible to interference.

Comment: the point it, with skype it works, I see no way skype could improve connection of another program if its related to interferences, plus the wifi is 3 meters away and I have an high speed connection

Comment: Does Skype work fine while you're running another process that doesn't?  :P

Comment: yes, I also found, bittorrent makes things work aswell, its like it wakes up the wifi card while streaming data

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this is an issue I've seen in my shop a few times since Win10 release -- Wireless worked fine with previous OS. After Win10 upgrade the wireless is iffy: Sometimes works great, sometimes cuts off randomly, sometimes not at all. LAN connections work fine.

95% of the computers I've experienced the issue had wireless + bluetooth cards. Not sure if its just coincidence since most newer cards have both or not, but we've found great success by replacing the wireless + bluetooth cards with just an older wireless card with no BT.

I haven't done extensive tests so I'm not 100% on the cause, however I know the constant is "Win10." You can find a new wireless cards cheap online, or pull one out of an older laptop.

Good luck!